# interpolate a string with an incrementing number

Tags: ruby

Im trying to interpolate a string with a number and increment that number as I iterate a list of attendees...
String `"Hello #{name}. You are guest number #{num}."` I know how to iterate each guest name, but how do I get a number to increment within the string from `1..7`? I know this is simple. I am very beginner.

Tried everything.

```
def assign_rooms(attendees)
  room_assignments = []
  rooms.to_s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  attendees.each_with_index {|x| room_assignments<< "Hello #{x}! You'll be assigned room #{rooms}!"}
  room_assignments
end
```

Comment: Is the amount of rooms and attendees the same? Can you use the attendee's index as the room number? `attendees.each_with_index {|x, room| room_assignments<< "Hello #{x}! You'll be assigned room #{room + 1}!"}`

Comment: Yes, same number of attendees and rooms. I'll try your suggestion now.

Comment: Wow..thank you so much! I knew it was simple but I just couldnt get it..tried everything.

Comment: Great! I've posted that as a proper answer.

Comment: In your studies you might want to take advantage of SO's sister-site at Stack Exchange, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). There you can get helpful advice on how to improve your (working) code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Enumerable#each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) gives two arguments to the block: the item itself (the attendee), and the item's index which increments as desired. You can also combine  with [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-map) to avoid having to explicitly create and append the output to a second array. [`Enumerator#with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) allows specifying a start offset for the index (so that the room numbers are not zero-based).

```
def assign_rooms(attendees)
  attendees.map.with_index(1) {|attendee, room|
    "Hello #{attendee}! You'll be assigned room #{room}!"
  }
end

puts assign_rooms(['Alice', 'Bob', 'Jack'])
```

Outputs:

```
Hello Alice! You'll be assigned room 1!
Hello Bob! You'll be assigned room 2!
Hello Jack! You'll be assigned room 3!
```

Comment: Perfect! Makes complete sense. I think I was in a brain lock lol Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could also achieve your goal with an enumerator. Suppose the first room number is `2`.

```
attendees = %w| Flora Billy-Bob Hank Trixie Herb |
  #=> ["Flora", "Billy-Bob", "Hank", "Trixie", "Herb"]
```

```
nbr = 2.step
  #=> (2.step)

nbr.is_a?(Enumerator)
  #=> true

attendees.each { |name|
  puts "Hello, #{name}, you've been assigned to our best room, number #{nbr.next}!" }
Hello, Flora, you've been assigned to our best room, number 2!
Hello, Billy-Bob, you've been assigned to our best room, number 3!
Hello, Hank, you've been assigned to our best room, number 4!
Hello, Trixie, you've been assigned to our best room, number 5!
Hello, Herb, you've been assigned to our best room, number 6!
```

Note the following.

```
nbr.next #=> 7 
nbr.next #=> 8 
nbr.rewind
nbr.next #=> 2
```

See [Numeric#step](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Numeric.html#method-i-step), [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) and (only if you are curious) [Enumerator#rewind](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-rewind).

Answer (score 0):

For fun, I'd like to show a more structured way, using a [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Hash.html) as a model for storing information.

Let's use these input data:

```
rooms = [110, 111, 112, 210, 211, 212].map { |n| [n, {free: true, host: nil}] }.to_h
reception_queue  = %w|Kirk Picard Spock McCoy Riker LaForge|
```

Let's say one room is already booked:

```
rooms[210] = {free: false, host: 'Uhura'}
rooms #=> {110=>{:free=>true, :host=>nil}, 111=>{:free=>true, :host=>nil}, 112=>{:free=>true, :host=>nil}, 210=>{:free=>false, :host=>"Uhura"}, 211=>{:free=>true, :host=>nil}, 212=>{:free=>true, :host=>nil}}
```

Now we want to assign the free rooms to each attendee. It is required to find the first room available matching some condition (free, but in can be one bed, two beds, suite, etc, depending on the complexity of the model).

This can be achieved by [Enumerable#find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find):

```
rooms.find { |_, v| v[:free] }
#=> [110, {:free=>true, :host=>nil}]
```

Once we find a room, we want to assign the host there, removing her from the queue ([Array#shift](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-shift)). Breaking the loop if there is no match.

---

For example:

```
reception_queue.size.times do |person|
  nr = rooms.find { |_,v| v[:free] }
  break unless nr
  rooms[nr[0]][:host] = reception_queue.shift
  rooms[nr[0]][:free] = false
end
```

So you can end up with:

```
rooms #=> {110=>{:free=>false, :host=>"Kirk"}, 111=>{:free=>false, :host=>"Picard"}, 112=>{:free=>false, :host=>"Spock"}, 210=>{:free=>false, :host=>"Uhura"}, 211=>{:free=>false, :host=>"McCoy"}, 212=>{:free=>false, :host=>"Riker"}}
reception_queue #=> ["LaForge"]
```